# How to add error-checking for VLOOKUP in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, error-handling, vlookup

I am moving some excel formula to visual basic to save some file space.
One aspect I am struggling with is adding some error-checking.

I have a formula (in column 23/W):
`your text`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(W2, auditdata!A:D, 1, FALSE)),"room not audited", "room audited")

That I have re-written as visual basic code, but I am struggling to add the "On Error" statement.
I am using these instructions for reference: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement](https://stackoverflow.com)

Actually, the formula is a little more complicated - I need to check the values of two columns and if both exist in the Table Array I am checking, then return "audited" otherwise "not audited". I am simplifying the problem so I can better understand.

There will be two situations where an error can occur: if the cell checked is empty or it has a value that does not exist in the other data table. The VBA error is
Run-time error '1004':

The code so far is:

```
Sub CheckRoomAudited_Method()
    Dim AuditCheckCell As Range 'cell where the vlookup results are returned

    Dim TotaltoCheck As Long 'last row in the column to check
    TotaltoCheck = Worksheets("RoomUse").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row 'using first column as some data missing in lookup range column
    
    Dim EndofAuditRange As Long
    EndofAuditRange = Worksheets("auditdata").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'this in the TableArray that will be checked
    
    Dim AuditCheckColumn As Range 'column where the vlookup results are returned
    Set AuditCheckColumn = Worksheets("RoomUse").Range(Worksheets("RoomUse").Cells(2, 23), Worksheets("RoomUse").Cells(TotaltoCheck, 23)) 'seemed long-winded to specify but could not get it to work otherwise     
    
    Dim VlookupValueColumn As Range 'need to check values in this column to see if they exist in other sheet
    Set VlookupValueColumn = Worksheets("RoomUse").Range(Worksheets("RoomUse").Cells(2, 37), Worksheets("RoomUse").Cells(TotaltoCheck, 37))
    
    Dim TableArrayRange As Range 'TableArray that will be checked
    Set TableArrayRange = Worksheets("auditdata").Range(Worksheets("auditdata").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("auditdata").Cells(EndofAuditRange, 4))
    
    For Each AuditCheckCell In AuditCheckColumn
        'loop through column number 37 ("AK:AK") and check whether each value exist in the other table/sheet
    'write the value if it exist or "room not audited" if it does not exist in column 23/W
        AuditCheckCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(AuditCheckCell.Offset(0, 14), TableArrayRange, 1, False)
    Next AuditCheckCell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is TableArray an actual Excel table?  Do you get a Table Design tab appear in the ribbon when you select a cell within the table?

Comment: Use `application.vlookup` and assign the result to a variant variable. You can then test that with iserror: `if iserror(result_variable) then` and react accordingly. Note however that vlookup is not going to work with multiple columns to check.

Comment: You can shorten that AuditCheckColumn reference using [With...End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) -  `With Worksheets("RoomUse"): Set AuditCheckColumn = .Range(.Cells(2, 23), .Cells(TotaltoCheck, 23)): End With`.   `:` signifies a line break.

Comment: Please, try `AuditCheckCell.Value = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(AuditCheckCell.Offset(0, 14), TableArrayRange, 1, False), "Not Existing")`.

Comment: Thank you, everyone for the suggestions. In the end have gone with the answer from FunThomas though the one-line code from @FaneDuru also works perfectly.
Darren Bartrup-Cook, thank you for the End...End With suggestion - I had thought it was used more for changing the properties of objects. 
Also, TableArrayRange is not an Excel table - it is a range of cells in my second worksheet. I named it like that as it is similar to the vlookup reference.
Rory, I have used your suggestion along with the one from FunThomas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways to execute `VLookup` from VBA: The first is the method you are using (`WorksheetFunction.VLookup`), the other is `Application.VLookup`.

Basically, they do the same, the only difference is the error-handling.

`WorksheetFunction.VLookup` throws a runtime error if a value cannot be found. You need to catch this error by yourself using the `On Error`-Statements:

```
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = "(not found)"  ' Or whatever value you want to put into the cell if not found
On Error Resume Next    
myValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(AuditCheckCell.Offset(0, 14), TableArrayRange, 1, False)
On Error Goto 0
AuditCheckCell.Value = myValue
```

`Application.VLookup` doesn't throw a runtime error. Instead, if the value is not found, it returns an error value. When you write that value into a cell, the cell will display `#N/A` - that's exactly what is returned from the VLookup-Function in an Excel formula. In VBA, you can check this using the functions `IsError`, or, more specifically, `IsNA`.

```
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = Application.VLookup(AuditCheckCell.Offset(0, 14), TableArrayRange, 1, False)
if IsNA(myValue) Then
    AuditCheckCell.Value = "(not found)" 
Else
    AuditCheckCell.Value = myValue
End If
```

Comment: Thank you @FunThomas for the suggestion and the explanation. 
I am not sure I understand it completely but had previously understood that Application was like an object so Application functions can be used, but in other situations WorksheetFunctions are more appropriate. 
I have used the code you suggested, it is straightforward and works. Though I had to add Application. in front of IsNa. 
Also, I only need to know whether the value is found or not found rather than the value itself and so have changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the default value of your range to the "not found" case, and then if the lookup is successful, replace it.  Like this:

```
For Each AuditCheckCell In AuditCheckColumn
        'loop through column number 37 ("AK:AK") and check whether each value exist in the other table/sheet
    'write the value if it exist or "room not audited" if it does not exist in column 23/W

    ' Default value
    AuditCheckCell.Value = "room not audited"

   ' Try to lookup the value
    On Error Resume Next
    AuditCheckCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(AuditCheckCell.Offset(0, 14), TableArrayRange, 1, False)
    On Error GoTo 0

Next AuditCheckCell
```

This will set the range's value to "room not audited" by default.  Then, we ignore errors, and try the lookup.  If the lookup is succesfful, the range's value is replaced with the lookup.  If the lookup throws an error, we move on to the next line, which is to stop ignoring errors.

Comment: This would write the cell value twice for every cell. Given the fact that the interface between Excel and VBA is slow, this should be avoided. It's much faster to use an intermediate variable (see my answer).

Comment: Thank you @TehDrunkSailor. I have gone with the suggestion from FunThomas.